# How do I vertically align the content in these grid cells in a bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've got a basic bootstrap grid with two rows and I'm trying to align the content vertically in these cells but no matter what I try the content doesn't seem to budge..

I've tried adding various classes to the rows and container div, i.e. align-middle, align-items-center but nothing seems to do anything.

```
<div id="header">
<p>< BACK TO HOMEPAGE</p>
</div>
<div id="main-content" style="height:85vh;">
</div>
<div id="menu-bar">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center ">
        <div class="row border-bottom border-dark">
          <div class="col">
          Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col col-3">
            6
          </div>
          <div class="col col-2">
            7
          </div>
          <div class="col col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Play Video</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="font-size: smaller;">
          <div class="col col-3">
            1
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col col-3">
            Colour
          </div>
          <div class="col col-4">
            Preview text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```html
<div class="row border-bottom border-dark">
```

To

```html
<div class="row border-bottom border-dark align-items-center">
```

Here's a JSFiddle with that change. I've added a border to each `div`, so you can see that it is centered vertically. http://jsfiddle.net/bqfa74y0/

If you want the lower row to be centered vertically, just add `align-items-center` to the class of the row.

---

I would also strongly recommend that you change:

```html
<p>< BACK TO HOMEPAGE</p>
```

To

```html
<p>&lt; BACK TO HOMEPAGE</p>
```

Because `<` has a special meaning in HTML (it's for starting/ending tags), so using it as text could have unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```css
 .menu-bar{
  length: 200px;
  width: 100%
}



 .col{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 11%;
  margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<p> BACK TO HOMEPAGE</p>
</div>
<div id="main-content" style="height:85vh;">
</div>
<div id="menu-bar">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center ">
        <div class="row border-bottom border-dark">
          <div class="col">
          Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col col-3">
            6
          </div>
          <div class="col col-2">
            7
          </div>
          <div class="col col-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Play Video</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="font-size: smaller;">
          <div class="col col-3">
            1
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            Preview text
          </div>
          <div class="col col-3">
            Colour
          </div>
          <div class="col col-4">
            Preview text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```